# ANTLR V4 lexer lookahead regex

Tags: regex, parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I'm trying to write a grammar for an XML-like language, where we use << instead of < characters.
This is a partial snap of the lexer, where TEXT represents the text between (outside) tags:

```
OPEN  : '<<' ;
CLOSE : '>>' ;
TEXT  : ~[^<]+ ;
```

The definition for TEXT above is clearly wrong, because it will stop at the first occurrence of < even when one is not followed by another <.
I am looking for a way to define "capture everything until you encounter a <<" but don't include the << as part of the match.

So something like this won't work either:

```
TEXT  : .*? '<<' ;
```

Is there a way to accomplish that in ANTLR4?

-- TR

Answer (score 5):

No need for a lookahead here, the following should do the trick:

```
TEXT  : ( ~'<' | '<' ~'<' )+ ;
```

That is: match a series of non `<` characters, or a single `<` followed by something else.

By the way, ANTLR's syntax is different for negative character classes. You should write `~[a-z]` instead of `[^a-z]` for instance.

You may also want to take a look at the [XML example grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/xml), it uses lexer modes to differentiate tokens inside tags, which may also prove useful for your grammar.

Comment: What if the `~'<'` piece is more than a single char? Example: `~'TERM'`. This doesn't work for ANTLR unfortunately.